# Advice on calculating a function to describe upper bound of data

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I have a scatter plot of a dataset and I am interested in calculating the upper bound of the data. I don't know if this is a standard statistical approach so what I was considering doing was splitting the X-axis data into small ranges, calculating the max for these ranges and then trying to identify a function to describe these points. Is there a function already in R to do this?

If it's relevant there are 92611 points.

[image]

Comment: There's no reason why you can't do what you describe. However without any statistical basis for your data I don't think there's an answer to your validity question. You're basically joining the dots and then smoothing.

Comment: @Spacedman - I agree about the validity issue; I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: What I mean is that computing the upper bound of the _data_ is trivial. Computing the upper bound of any hypothetical process that your data may or may not come from is not trivial. The upper bound could be infinite, as in a Normal distribution. The regression models given in other answers here are dependent on the assumption that your data comes from some model. The usual question you'll get from statistician applies here: "What is the real question you are trying to ask?". :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might like to look into quantile regression, which is available in the **[quantreg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/index.html)** package. Whether this is useful will depend on whether you want the absolute maximum within your "windows" are whether some extreme quantile, say 95th or 99th, is acceptable? If you are not familiar with quantile regression, then consider the linear regression which fits a model for the expectation or mean response, conditional upon the model covariates. Quantile regression for the middle quantile (0.5) would fit a model to the median response, conditional upon the model covariates.

Here is an example using the **quantreg** package, to show you what I mean. First, generate some dummy data similar to the data you show:

```
set.seed(1)
N <- 5000
DF <- data.frame(Y = rev(sort(rlnorm(N, -0.9))) + rnorm(N),
                 X = seq_len(N))
plot(Y ~ X, data = DF)
```

Next, fit the model to the 99th percentile (or the 0.99 quantile):

```
mod <- rq(Y ~ log(X), data = DF, tau = .99)
```

To generate the "fitted line", we predict from the model at 100 equally spaced values in `X`

```
pDF <- data.frame(X = seq(1, 5000, length = 100))
pDF <- within(pDF, Y <- predict(mod, newdata = pDF))
```

and add the fitted model to the plot:

```
lines(Y ~ X, data = pDF, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

This should give you this:

[image: quantile regression output]

Comment: This example also suggests that the quantile regression might be better on the log-scale for x for the type of the data in the original post.

Comment: +1 for illustrating use of the `quantreg` package, which I found useful in my own work recently. Also I would suggest a good first step is to bin the X values (as the OP said), and plot the Y-quantile against the X-bins (say mid point), so you can visualize the dependence -- is it logarithmic, etc. And then use `quantreg` on the appropriately transformed Y variable (because `quantreg` will only do *linear* quantile regression).

Comment: @pchalasani; it will do a lot more than that. The package vignette includes sections on *nonlinear* quantile regression and also models with smoothing splines etc. If you mean `qr` then yes, it will only fit linear models, but then we can include spline terms on the RHS of the formula and get a nonlinear model. *quantreg* is a great package and something I have been meaning to look at in greater detail for a while.

Answer (score 3):

I would second Gavin's nomination for using quantile regression. Your data might be simulated with your X and Y each log-normally distributed. You can see what a plot of the joint distribution of two independent (no imposed correlation, but not necessarily cor(x,y)==0)  log-normal variates looks like if you run:

```
x <- rlnorm(1000, log(300), sdlog=1)
y<- rlnorm(1000, log(7), sdlog=1)
plot(x,y, cex=0.3)
```

[image]

You might consider looking at their individual distributions with qqplot (in the base plotting functions) remembering that the tails of such distrubutions can behave in surprising manner. You should be more interested in how well the bulk of the values fit a particular distribution than the extremes ... unless of course your applications are in finance or insurance. Don't want another global financial crisis because of poor modeling assumptions about tail behavior,  now do we?

```
qqplot(x, rlnorm(10000, log(300), sdlog=1) )
```

Comment: I love this graph image.  It looks like you printed it, faxed it to yourself, then scanned it as an image.

Comment: Actually I uploaded a pdf to imgur.com and pasted in a link. I may have gotten the reference wrong since in my browser it does not seem as smooth as Gavin's

Comment: I just created a png via the `png()` device. You can click the picture button in the edit toolbar when composing/editing answers and a dialogue pops up which allows you to navigate to a location on your local storage/drives to upload the image from. It does the uploading to imgur.com and embeds the correct link for you - you don't need to do anything extra after you generate the figure locally.

Comment: @ Gavin. Thanks. I'll see if a png image looks better next time, but since Joshua likes this one so much I may leave in its current ragged state.