# Dummy for lower tertile normalized by multiple variables

Tags: r

I need to find the proportion of respondents whose hand grip strength was in the bottom tertile normalised for age, gender, weight and height.

First, I am trying to normalize `grip` strength given `age`, `male`, `height` and `weight`. Secondly, I try to create a variable given the `tertiles` of this normalized `grip` strength variable. And lastly, I try to create a dummy equal to `1` if an individual is in the lower tertile.

So far I have constructed this code, but it is not really working:

```
df <- within(df, normal <- ave(grip, male, age, weight, height ,FUN=function(x) (x-min(x))/diff(range(x))))
df$tertile <- ave(df$normal, 
                 FUN=function(x){cut(x, labels=1:3, breaks=quantile(x, probs = 0:3/3, na.rm = TRUE), include.lowest=TRUE)})
df$lowgrip <- ifelse(df$tertile==1, 1, 0)
```

Data could look like this:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  age = sample(50:79, 40, replace = TRUE),
  male = sample(c("1", "0"), 40, replace = TRUE),
  grip = sample(5:80, 40, replace = TRUE),
  weight = sample(50:100, 40, replace = TRUE),
  height = sample(150:200, 40, replace = TRUE)
)
```

However, my real data has around 7000 observations.

Comment: I don't think "normalization" is being well-defined here. Seems like you would want to do quantile regression to construct a predicted quantile of 0.33 in the present of covariates. Then identify cases where the observed value is below the prediction.

Comment: Earlier question involving QReg prediction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594370/advice-on-calculating-a-function-to-describe-upper-bound-of-data